# How to recursively find all folders containing a .hg folder in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, mercurial

I am trying to write a script in PowerShell to backup our collection of Mercurial repositories.

I started with this:

```
$repos=Get-ChildItem C:\hgrepos|Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
```

This will get the first level of folders under C:\hgrepos, which normally would be fine, as this is where our repositories are located. However, subrepositories exist. So I need to go recursive. And most importantly, *only folders containing a .hg subfolder should be listed*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `-recurse` flag in `Get-ChildItem`

It will be something like this:

```
gci c:\hgrepos -recurse -include ".hg" | %{$_.Parent}
```

Comment: You might want to filter for folders to be sure that `.hg` is a folder `gci c:\hgrepos -recurse -include ".hg" | ?{$_.PSIsContainer} | %{$_.Parent}`

Comment: @jonZ - Actually, I did test it out. It doesn't get parents that have a file named .hg.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this PowerShell function to backup our Mercurial repositories:

```
function BackupHg
{
    param($repositoryRoot, $destination)

    # The path to the Hg executable
    $hg = """C:\Python26\hg.bat"""

    # Get the list of repos
    Get-ChildItem $repositoryRoot | 
        Where { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true } |
        ForEach -Process { 
            $repo = $_.FullName 
            $folder = $_.Name

            if (Test-Path "$repo\.hg") {
                $cmdLine = "$hg clone -U $repo $destination\$folder"
                cmd /c $cmdLine
            }
            else {
                New-Item "$destination\$folder" -type directory
                BackupHg "$repositoryRoot\$folder" "$destination\$folder"
            }
        }    
}
```

You pass in the root folder and backup destination and it finds all folders, tests if it is a Mercurial repo (looking for a .hg directory) and clones the repo to the backup destination.  If the folder is not a Mercurial repo then it does the recursion itself.

It's done like this because we use folders to organise our repos so all the code for each client is in its own folder separate from other clients.

One last point.  The presence of Mercurial sub-repositories doesn't mean that you need to recurse.  Unless you have a repository with a working copy, your sub-repo won't be stored in the repository and should be backed up by whatever system it is stored on.  If that is the same system as the repository then it will be another repository in your repositories folder and will be backup up by the above script.

For example, we have a WebApp repository with a WebControls sub-repository for a client and the file structure is as follows:

```
C:\Repositories\Hg\Client\WebApp
C:\Repositories\Hg\Client\WebControls
```

WebControls is not stored in the WebApp folder even though it is a sub-repository of it.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the $backup_path and the hardcoded path D:\Repositories\Mercurial?

Comment: Oops... those are errors where I missed making global variables / hard-coded paths into parameters when I converted the into a function.  I'll fix it, test it and edit my answer shortly.

Comment: I've fixed that bug now - it wouldn't have backed up more than one folder deep (which we have just added to our structure today, coincidentally, so our backup would have failed tonight)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the script below. Thanks to Steve Kaye and manojlds for providing much needed feedback!

```
function BackupHg
{
    param($repositoryRoot, $destination)

    Remove-Item "$destination\*" -recurse

    # The path to the Hg executable
    $hg = """C:\Python27\Scripts\hg.bat"""

    # Get the list of repos
    Get-ChildItem $repositoryRoot -recurse | 
        Where { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true } |
        ForEach -Process { 
            $repo = $_.FullName 
            $folder = $_.FullName.Replace($repositoryRoot, $destination)


            if (Test-Path "$repo\.hg") {
                if (!(Test-Path "$folder")) {
                    New-Item "$folder" -type directory
                }
                $cmdLine = "$hg clone -U $repo $folder"
                write-host $cmdLine
                cmd /c $cmdLine
            }
        }    
}
```